# Древо Drag and Drop React,Проблема вложенных сущностей

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-n-drop, draggable

С сервера мне приходит древо департаментов структура такая , пример:

```
{id: 13, name: 'тест', code: 'test', subs: Array(0), children: {…}, …}
{id: 14, name: 'тест', code: 'test', subs: Array(0), children: {…}, …}
```

у каждого департамента есть свойство children которое представляет собой объект с сущностми которые являются дочерними от этого департамента , пример :

```
children: Array(2)
0: {id: 2, name: 'ттс', code: 'tts', subs: Array(0), head: null}
1: {id: 5, name: 'тст', code: 'tts', subs: Array(4), head: {…}}
```

задание состоит в том, что нужно реализовать функционал для вложение одной сущности в другую

чтобы выглядело примерно так

```
---->тест1
         |
         |---->дочерняя сущность-| 
         |                       |-->дочерняя сущность
```

я реализовал несколько функций слушателей событий 1 ---

2-функция отвечающая за логику самого drag and drop

```
const dropHandler = (e: React.DragEvent, targetItem: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    setCurrentList((prevList) => {
      let updatedList = [...prevList];
      const draggedEntity = updatedList.find(
        (item) => item.id === Number(currCard.id)
      );
    
      const changedList = prevList.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === targetItem.id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            children: [...item.children, draggedEntity],
          };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });

      const targetEntity = updatedList.find(
        (item) => item.id === targetItem.id
      );
      if (targetEntity && !isDescendantDragged(targetEntity, draggedEntity)) {
        const prevEntity = changedList.find(
          (item) => item.children && item.children.includes(draggedEntity)
        );
        if (prevEntity) {
          prevEntity.children = prevEntity.children.filter(
            (child: any) => child.id !== draggedEntity.id
          );
        }
      }

      return changedList;
    });
  };
```

проблема этой функции заключается в том что если я например хочу у департамента a перенесети 1й его дочерний элемент во второй то получится не такая структура `{name:a ,children:[{name:tst,children:[{name:tst2}]}` а такая : `{name:a ,children:[{name:tst}],[{name:tst2}]}`, то есть элементы будут находиться на одном уровне а не вкладываться